# AS/400 scheule a WRKJOBSCDE job first business day of the month

Tags: ibm-midrange

On my AS/400, I am trying to schedule a job on the job scheduler (ADDJOBSCDE) which runs on the first business day of every month. Putting SCDDATE(*MONTHSTR) is not enough because that would run the job on a Sunday if the month happened to start on a Sunday.

I was thinking of putting the parameters RELDAYMON(1) FRQ(*MONTHLY) SCDDAY(*MON, *TUE, *WED, *THU, *FRI) but does this do the first business day, or does it do 5 times a month, the first Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, but not empirically, the task might best be implemented with what is proposed; i.e. `ADDJOBSCDE FRQ(*MONTHLY) SCDDATE(*NONE) SCDDAY(*MON *TUE *WED *THU *FRI) RELDAYMON(1)`. But necessarily, in conjunction with a change whereby the program that gets invoked would check the business calendar, test to see if the current date is a *business day*, and if so, then continue monthly processing, else return/exit without further processing; probably best also, logging that the program determined the scheduled date was not accurate per a condition that is presumed innocuous, according to the design/implementation, such that review of the completed job, what was **not accomplished** by that successfully started and completed job can be easily understood.

Another option [one that I prefer] is to use the *same business calendar* alluded-to above, from which to generate each monthly Job Scheduled Entry (JOBSCDE) for the upcoming year; i.e. the submitted work for each month would be defined in a separate entry, each with a specific Scheduled Date (SCDDATE) rather than using a frequency (FRQ). Note: The final month, as detected by the program, could result in a presumed-valid request to add the same jobs for the upcoming year; i.e. with the expectation that the calendar already has the date-entries from the next year.

If the business calendar is stored in a TABLE, then a TRIGGER could be defined to react to changes [or new data] with regard to what is defined as the *first business day of any month*; i.e. the business-rule that is defined by what is the 1st business day of the month is to ensure that job gets added or updated in the JOBSCDE. Although without any triggers the jobs for an entire year could be schedule from a planned calendar, the trigger allows for changing situations; i.e. if the business calendar that was planned-on last year changes for any reason, the business-rule that defines the noted job should occur on that schedule, is automatically adjusted or added, according to the changed calendar.